# Triggering Apache Beam (Python) run from GAE Cronjob

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

In replacing my old `appengine-mapreduce` job, I need a way to trigger this python dataflow job from my cron.

I have read https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/04/scheduling-dataflow-pipelines-using-app-engine-cron-service-or-cloud-functions , but am unclear on the full translation for Python.

Cloud Functions do not have python installed, and I'm not sure if/how it's possible to install a portable python. So I assume triggering from my Managed VM Python instance will be easier...as far as I can tell, it will be something like this:

- I am using GAE Flexible VMs (no sandbox).
- I can include the apache_beam libraries (to run `my_dataflow.py`) into my docker image.
- I can upload these files with my project push so they are accessible from the VM disk: `my_dataflow.py`, `setup.py` (that installs my library dependencies), and `apache-beam.tar.gz` (since I'm writing against the 0.7.0 API that's not yet released on PyPI)
- I can call `my_dataflow.run()` pointing PipelineOptions at the `setup.py` and `apache-beam.tar.gz`.

Is that it, or am I missing any other steps? Hoping to avoid barking up the wrong tree here, and worried about running into known impassable roadblocks after spending a few hours pushing-and-repushing trying to get this working.

Comment: Does your Dataflow pipeline have to be in Python? If not, and it can be in Java, then you could simply use Dataflow's templates feature, and trigger the pipeline(s) from cloud functions. https://shinesolutions.com/2017/03/23/triggering-dataflow-pipelines-with-cloud-functions/

Comment: My project is fully Python/JS. Not looking to rewrite the dataflow in Java (and end up with *zero* code reuse) just to get a cronjob working. Are "templates" a Java-only feature?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, template are currently Java only.

You may be able to use this technique instead to invoke your pipeline periodically instead. This doesn't use a template pipeline, but instead launches a normal pipeline. You can setup a cloud function to launch the pipeline by running a subprocess to launch the pipeline. There are various ways of invoking the cloud function. This one uses app engine cron service.

https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/04/scheduling-dataflow-pipelines-using-app-engine-cron-service-or-cloud-functions

Comment: Yes, the link you just shared is the one in my original question up above. In the article, they upload JRE and a JAR to the cloud function. In the case of Python...would I somehow need to upload a full Python install? That seems...prone to problems. Thus, investigating if I can just call it from Python code, and what's entailed.